# Vue.js load CSS based on subdomain

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a Vue js application made using the Vue cli 3. I am using sass loader and node-sass in my project.

If I have multiple subdomain for same code eg `site1.mysite.com` and `site2.mysite.com` how can I load a different css file depending on the subdomain?

I already have a JavaScript function in a file to return the subdomain value.

In my `app.vue` file I have a scss style section is there a way to access this function in the scss and then load the relevant CSS for the subdomain assuming that I have named the css/scss files in a structured way.

**Example:**

`site1_theme.scss` and `site2_theme.scss` in a root folder `/assets/scss`

Or is there a different way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have yo tried using dynamic imports?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

So something along the lines of:

```js
if (domain === 'site1.mysite.com') {
    import('/assets/scss/site1_theme.scss');
} else {
    import('/assets/scss/site2_theme.scss');
}
```